# Rails: Ignore nested attributes with a certain name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-attributes

Basing this functionality off of Ryan Bates [Nested Model Form](http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2) tutorials, when I submit my form, I've got this set of data that's submitted:

```
{
    "authenticity_token"=>"mdohADjieoqUwOwUK/H52TAiH5HdFYQtTbTuMJtDJE8=",
     "utf8"=>"✓",
     "id"=>"92",
     "survey"=>
    {
        "questions_attributes"=>
        {
            "1299616889104"=>
            {
                "display_type"=>"",
                 "text"=>"",
                 "other"=>"0",
                 "display_order"=>"0",
                 "answer_choices"=>"",
                 "item_type"=>"multiple_choice"
            },
             "new_questions"=>
            {
                "display_type"=>"compare",
                 "pick"=>"one",
                 "text"=>"",
                 "other"=>"0",
                 "display_order"=>"0",
                 "answer_choices"=>"",
                 "item_type"=>"compare"
            }
        },
         "id"=>"92"
    }
}
```

What I need to figure out how to do is ignore the `new_questions` section. I know you can add `reject_if` to `accepts_nested_attributes_for` but there are hidden fields that are included and pre-populated with data, so I can't ignore based on empty fields.

So how can ignore `new_questions` in my example data?

I'm running Rails 3.0.3

Answer (score 0):

i would look into using conditional validation.  heres a [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/41-conditional-validations) on it dealing with passwords, but you can easily adapt something similar for your situation

Comment: Sorry, I'm not really following how to implement this in relation to `accepts_nested_attributes_for`

Comment: its possible i have misinterpreted your question, but i assumed you wanted to ignore the field because it was messing with your validations, no?  in that case adding conditional validation will allow you to ignore the field unless you specify that it should be taken into consideration when working with the model

Comment: The fact that we're using `accepts_nested_attributes_for` I think changes what needs to be done. As far as I can tell, I can't find a way to detect the presence of `new_questions`, which is a problem as far as just writing a simple conditional validation.

Comment: sorry i guess im just not 100% clear on what you are asking then.  are you trying to simply ignore the field or validate if its there or not?  if you are just trying to detect if its there or not, then after posting you can do something like if params[:search][:question_attributes][:new_questions].blank?  || params[:search][:question_attributes][:new_questions].nil? yada yada yada